# Mount NFS on a remote host through a intermediate host

Tags: linux, mount, forwarding, nfs

My scenario is:

```
hostA: /A_NFS/
hostB: hostA:/A_NFS/ on /B_NFS type nfs
hostC: hostB:/B_NFS/ on /C_NFS type nfs
```

hostA is reachable for hostB, but not reachable for hostC.

hostB is reachable for hostC.

In this scenario, I can't get any content in hostC:/C_NFS.

Is there a way to make the things in hostA:/A_NFS/ could be seen in hostC:/C_NFS by mount? Or other ways can make the hostB forward the content of hostA to hostC?

Comment: Is this your same case?: http://serverfault.com/questions/55025/nfs-exporting-a-directory-thats-already-nfs-mounted-on-the-server

Comment: No. It's different. It's permission problem in that case. I just get an empty /C_NFS without any mount error.

Comment: I think I've found the solution. SSH tunnel can solve this problem. http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/ssh-tunnel.html